# Generic map function will not accept valid closure

Tags: swift, generics

I have the following code in a 'SquareMatrix <T: HasZeroOne>' class whose data 'data' is stored in a [[T]] double array. I made this mapping function to mimic the standard Swift one.

```
public func map<S: HasZeroOne>(transform: (T) -> S) -> SquareMatrix<S> {
    return SquareMatrix(data: data.map{(row: [T]) in row.map({(col: T) in transform(col)})})!
}
```

At first I tried the simpler syntax:

```
public func map<S: HasZeroOne>(transform: (T) -> S) -> SquareMatrix<S> {
    return SquareMatrix(data: data.map{$0.map(transform)})!
}
```

But got the following error in both cases:

> Cannot convert value of type '(T) -> S' to expected argument type '(_) -> _'

I'm completely lost. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is always the way, I got an answer 5 minutes later. Not that the error message helped at all. The following works:

```
public func map<S: HasZeroOne>(transform: (T) -> S) -> SquareMatrix<S> {
    return SquareMatrix<S>(data: data.map{$0.map(transform)})!
}
```

Note the `<S>`.

Hope someone finds this a useful hint!